# Writing mathematical texts in German

Tags: phrase, mathematics, book, scientific-language

I am looking for something like an "encyclopedia" of practical guidelines on writing mathematical papers/texts in German (lists of common phrases in mathematics in German, common sentence constructions, etc.).

As an example of the kind of book I am looking for, I would like to mention ["Writing Mathematical papers in English"](http://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=34) by Jerzy Trzeciak. It is quite a useful practical guide for writing mathematical texts in English.

Is there a German equivalent of Trzeciak's book or a similar book in German that matches the above description?

Comment: So far, the closest approximation of Trzeciak's book in German that I found is [Das ist o.B.d.A. trivial!](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-8348-9075-7). But it has a rather introductory and elementary approach.

Comment: Sei *ε* kleiner 0 …

Comment: @Jan Sakrileg! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My recommendation is to try the soon-to-be-published book *Wie man mathematisch schreibt* by Burkhard Kümmerer, ISBN 978-3-658-01576-3. This should get the job done for you.

Comment: From the Springer's [product description](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783658015756), it looks like the kind of thing I am looking for. For learning more about the book, a preview would help, but I guess we will have to wait until 2016 for that. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: No worries, it was a pleasure to help. You could be lucky and the author might send you a preview if you ask him. Perhaps you try that?

Comment: @Zvonimir I asked someone about the publication date of the book, and the answer was "May, 2016".

Comment: Springer's [website](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783658015756#aboutBook) indicates 6 May 2016 as the release date (under "Softcover" in the box "Dieses Buch kaufen" on the right side you can find "Erscheinungstermin: Mai 6, 2016"). I do not think I will ask the author for a preview, as I do not need the book so urgently. Nevertheless, thank you for the suggestion.